# Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: incorrect program id for instruction

Tags: anchor-lang, solana-cli, solang

this is my code and error is occur when i calling new method :

```
 import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
    import { Program } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
    import { Starter } from "../target/types/starter";
    
      // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
      const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
      anchor.setProvider(provider);
    
      const dataAccount = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();
      const wallet = provider.wallet;
    
      const program = anchor.workspace.Starter as Program<Starter>;
    
     async function check(){
         // Add your test here.
         const tx = await program.methods.new(wallet.publicKey)
         .accounts({ dataAccount: dataAccount.publicKey })
         .signers([dataAccount]).rpc();
       console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);
    
       const val1 = await program.methods.get()
         .accounts({ dataAccount: dataAccount.publicKey })
         .view();
    
       console.log("state", val1);
    
       await program.methods.flip()
         .accounts({ dataAccount: dataAccount.publicKey })
         .rpc();
    
    
       const stringSing = await program.methods.sing("I am saurav").accounts({dataAccount:dataAccount.publicKey}).rpc()
    
       console.log("stringSing",stringSing)
    
       const stringValue = await program.methods.line().accounts({dataAccount:dataAccount.publicKey}).view()
    
       console.log("value",stringValue)
      }
    
      check()

this is my anchor.toml file : 
[features]
seeds = false
skip-lint = false
[programs.localnet]
starter = "C5fvGN6yt7UCPcShNNfDZdjgjf6mbmhVMAD3hwY7N6bY"

[registry]
url = "http://localhost:8899/"

[provider]
cluster = "Localnet"
wallet = "/home/saurav/.config/solana/id.json"

[scripts]
test = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/**/*.ts"
```

Comment: If you're on anchor-cli v 0.28.0 run `anchor keys sync`. If not,  run `anchor keys list` and then copy the displayed program ID to match that in `declare_id!()` in `lib.rs`, and also update the program-id in `anchor.toml` to match.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the program ID you have written in your Rust code?

```
declare_id!("THE ID")
```